# storing the values into the cookie and displaying those values on page load

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

hi i have an php form which contains many fields, now i tried to write the code for storing all those values into an array and store them in a cookie in javascript. the code is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setDate()
{
var today = new Date();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var day = today.getDate();
var year = today.getFullYear();
document.forms['form1'].elements['date'].value= month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}

function add_newoption(optionname)
{
  document.getElementById(optionname).InnerHTML = "";
}
var win = null;
function optionWindow(mypage,myname,w,h){
LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2: 0;
TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2: 0;
settings =
'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition;
win = window.open(mypage,myname,settings);
win.focus();
}

function setAction(act)
{
    document.forms['form1'].action = act;
    document.forms['form1'].submit();
}

</script>
```

and the code for the form is as follows:

```
<body onLoad="setDate();">
<br/>
<center>
<fieldset class="style1" style="width:800px; background-color:#FFFFFF">
<h4 align="center"> Designer Form </h4>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" >
  <table width="700" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="text-align:left; padding: 25px 0px 25px 0px;">
    <tr>
      <td width="174" align="right">Date:</td>
      <td width="331"><input name="date" type="text" size="10" readonly/></td>
      <td width="175" style="text-align:center;">Order Number:
      <input name="order_num" type="text" size="10" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;"><input name="orderdetails" type="submit" value="Get Order Details" onClick="setAction('?action=getorder');"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td colspan='4'>     <input name="email" id="email" type="hidden" value=""/>     </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">First Name:</td>
      <td><input name="fname" type="text" value=""/></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Last Name:</td>
      <td><input name="lname" type="text" value=""/></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td align="right">Image Submitted:</td>
      <td><input name="image" type="text" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">General Comments: </td>
      <td><textarea name="gen_comments" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Internal Comments:</td>
      <td><textarea name="int_comments" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Quality of the File:</td>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding-right:4px">
       <select name="quality">
       <option>Select One</option><option value="good">Good</option><option value="ok">A bit low but we can use it</option><option value="low">Low. We are concerned it might effect the qaulity of the final</option><option value="not good">Not good. We cannot work with it</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="test">test</option><option value="lisa">Lisa1</option><option value="bbb">aaa</option>        <!--option value="good">Good</option>
       <option value="ok">A bit low but we can use it</option>
       <option value="low">Low. We are concerned it might effect the qaulity of the final </option>
       <option value="not good">Not good. We can't work with it</option-->
        </select>
```

now what i want to do here is to get all these values entered in the form to store into an array and have to set cookie to retrieve them when the page re-loads...
how can i write a function for that using javascript and where to call that function in the form for getting those values into the form on page reloads..??
Any help will be needful to me....thanks in advance..

Comment: So you want to write cookies in javascript?

Comment: yes..but the values have to take from the form.

Answer (score 0):

well i think you should use `localStorage.setItem("DataKey","DataValue");` for store any value.
and for getting value you can use `localStorage.getItem("DataKey");`

FF,chrome,safari are support localStorage but i dont know about IE.